# How to find difference of two columns using in Left Outer Join in SQL Sever 2005?

Tags: sql-server-2005, join, left-join

I have two Tables 
Let suppose A and B
Now suppose the structure of table A is Like that

```
id     stock
 37      1
 40      1 
 37      1 
 40      1
 37      1
 37      1
```

And B is like that

```
id     stock
37      1
37      1 
40      1
```

**Now i want to write a query that give me sum of specific id stock in (table A - Table B) and if that id does not exist in table B then only stock from A.
So i will expect result like that**

```
id     stock

40      1  
37      2
```

I thought that left join will be possible option here and i write query like that

```
SELECT A.id, 
    SUM(CAST(isNull(A.Stock, 0) as int) - CAST(isNull(B.Stock, 0) as int) )'Stock'
    from  A
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
    B
    ON A.id = B.id
    group by A.id
```

But Problem is that the above query gives desired records but wrong quantity/Stocklevel as shown below:

```
id     stock
37      0
40      1
```

How can I resolve Stock Level issue.

Comment: The only relation between A and B is implictly given via the rownumber? That's one hell of a table design.

Comment: I very much doubt those results are accurate for given inputs. What happened to id 4? Why are there still 3 id's = 1?

Comment: In Table A and B the id is repeated due to some other entries in those tables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess you are looking for something like this.

```
select A.id, A.SumA - coalesce(B.SumB, 0) as stock
from (
       select A.id, sum(A.stock) as SumA
       from A
       group by A.id
     ) as A  
  left outer join
     (
       select B.id, sum(B.stock) as SumB
       from B
       group by B.id
     ) as B
    on A.id = B.id
```

Result:

```
id          stock
----------- -----------
37          2
40          1
```

[SE Data](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/60081/new)

Comment: The question's results were altered by another user. This is not equal to the result OP initially wrote but might very well be what he meant. Without OP chiming in, there is no way to know (and OP is *vewy vewy quiet*).

Comment: @M.NasserJavaid - My query gives your expected result. What is missing?

Comment: <g> And he's off again without explaining one thing. This brings up my favourite quote: *It always amazes me that people expect me to spend my time answering questions they won't spend their time asking. (George)*. +1 On your mindreading though.

Comment: @Lieven - I guess the best I can :)

Comment: @Mikael! Your query nicely work. Sir, can I ask you that whats wrong with my query? why it gave me wrong results?

Comment: @M.NasserJavaid - Sure. It is because of the join. You join 4 rows where id `37` in `A` against two rows with id `37` in `B`. That will result in a total of eight rows with a stock value of `1` on each row. The calculation then will be `8 - 8 = 0`.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT A.id, A.Stock - isNull(B.stock, 0) as Stock from A
LEFT OUTER JOIN B
ON A.id = B.id
```

That would be it I think.
PS. you group by something that you did not include in your case scenario. Your expected result is also not understandable to me (it conflicts with your problem description)